# Why is the same single result looping multiple times?

Tags: php, mysql, html

There are multiple blog entries and each should be shown once. There is a "comment" link that shows and hides the comments for every blog entry. I can't figure out why the same first result keeps showing up. It happens every time I add a new comment (currently there's 5 and the blog section is displayed 5 times and only the first comment is shown for each).
Based on whether the user is logged in the "comments" link either shows a a log in link or (if logged in) a form field to submit a comment.

```
<?php
$conn = mysql_connect("...", "...", "...");
mysql_select_db("...");
$result  = mysql_query("select * from blog");
$result2 = mysql_query("select * from blogcomment where blog.ID = blogcomment.blogID");
$i       = 1;
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    echo "<h1>$row[title]</h1>";
    echo "<p class ='second'>$row[blog_content]</p> ";
    echo "<p class='meta'>Posted by .... &nbsp;&bull;&nbsp; $row[date] &nbsp;&bull;&nbsp; <a href='#' onclick=\"toggle_visibility('something$i'); return false\">Comments</a><div id='something$i' style='display: none;'><p class='third' >";
    $i++;

    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result2))
    {
        echo "$row[commentdate] &nbsp;&bull;&nbsp; $row[username]</p><p>said:</p> <p>$row[comment]</p>";
        if (isset ($_SESSION["gatekeeper"])) {
            echo '<form method="post" action="postcomment.php"><input name="ID" type = "hidden" value = "' . $row[ID] . '" /><input name="comment" id="comment" type="text" style="margin-left:20px;"/><input type="submit" value="Add comment" /></form></div>';
        }
        else {
            echo '<p class="third"><a href="register.html">Signup </a>to post a comment</p></div>';
        }
    }
}
mysql_close($conn);
?>
```

Comment: Use [mysql_fetch_assoc](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-assoc.php)

Comment: I Would also recommend using single quotes around your array keys, $row[blah] should be $row['blah'], what if someone later comes along and does define('blah', 1234); . Happens rarely but it is good to avoid.

Comment: you'll have to use nested looping for what you desire.

Comment: ok could you check the updated code? now it shows the first blog and when I click 'comments' shows the second blog but I also get error messages instead of comment entries

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$i = 1; 
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
```